# Normalized Cross-Correlation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, normalization, cross-correlation

Is there a way of computing a normalized cross-correlation in MATLAB in 1D, meaning having as inputs two signals `s_1(t)` and `s_2(t)`, using the same philosophy of `xcorr` (which involves the FFT of the signals)?

MATLAB only contains the procedure for 2D signals (images). Computing the integral for many samples could be long.

[image: $$CC_N(\tau)=\frac{\int_{t_1}^{t_2} s_1(t)s_2(t+\tau)dt}{\sqrt{s_1^2(t)} \sqrt{s_2^2(t+\tau)}}$$]

Comment: Are you referring to [`normxcorr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html)? Did you try it with 1D signals? I don’t see why it wouldn’t work!

Comment: A 1D signal is simply a 1xN image. What’s the problem?

Comment: I think normxcorr2 is thought for templates, rather than simple cross-correlations, but I will go though it to see if it is possible to use it also for 1xN matrices.